# Connection to CRM failing

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

We have a system where user enters his data in a form and we save Data in CRM (Its in cloud so we have no access to it and all that). Now suddenly we have started getting error everytime, we try to send data.

Error we get is:
`An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.`

Inner Exception: `Authentication Failure DefaultURL`

It fails on every command i use like `RetrieveMultiple`, `Create` to name a few.

Nothing has been changed, it worked for 6-7 months without any change/problem and suddenly we are getting this error everytime we try to communicate with CRM system.

I have tried connecting to CRM after disabling our firewall and that didnt change anything, so nothing we have changed.

Does anyone getting this error recently? I have tried looking for this but their isn't much help I have found on any blog.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

After days of investigation, we found that the password we were using to connect to CRM expired and need updating. We updated the password and it worked.

Comment: I was exactly facing same issue and resolve issue as follow this answer. so this is the right answer.